# Interpolation and mapping between scattered vectors in two unequally dimensioned spaces

Tags: optimization, metric-spaces, regression, interpolation, machine-learning

### Imagine two spaces:

- An ‘input’ space with dimension $m$.
- An ‘output’ space with dimension $n$.
- $m \geq n$

There are points in each of these spaces defined such that some characteristic is defined. The characteristic is defined and valid in *both* spaces.

An **example*** might use RGB (Red, Green, Blue) values for the input and HSV (Hue, Saturation, Value) for the output.

<sup>(*the actual solution needs to generalize to accomodate arbitrary dimensions)</sup>

[image]

The characteristic of ‘greeny-ness’ is defined in the input space as the vector: $[0,255,0]$, and in the output space as: $[120,100,100]$.

‘red’, ‘black’, ‘yellow’ and  ‘random colour that *looks the same in both spaces*’ could be similarly defined.

Imagine now that a limited subset of colors has been defined in this way – i.e. there are $p$-pairs of $m$-dimensioned vectors coupled with their corresponding $n$-dimensioned vectors ($m=n=3$ in this case).

### The problem:

Given an arbitrary input vector, find (interpolate) the *corresponding* point in the *output* space that most exemplifies the 'characteristic' of that point (in the input space).

Using the color example, I might have all 8 corners of an RGB color cube defined as points on the input side – and their corresponding HSV values coupled with them as follows:

$$[0,0,0] \longleftrightarrow[0,0,0]$$$$
[255,0,0] \longleftrightarrow [0,100,100]$$$$
[0,255,0] \longleftrightarrow [120,100,100]$$$$
[255,255,0] \longleftrightarrow [60,100,100]$$$$
[0,0,255] \longleftrightarrow [240,100,100]$$$$
[255,0,255] \longleftrightarrow [300,100,100]$$$$
[0,255,255] \longleftrightarrow [180,100,100]$$$$
[255,255,255] \longleftrightarrow [0,0,100]$$

**Given $[128,128,128]$ (‘grey’) as the input point in the input space I’d expect to be able to find [0,0,50] (‘grey’ in HSV) in the output space.**

I know that I know that $[128,128,128]$ is right in the middle of the RGB cube with the Euclidean distances to all the 8 points being $ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \times 256$. It's also worth noting that while each RGB values range over 8-bits (256 each ), the HSV values range over 360°, 100 & 100 respectively...

Yes, there are known RGB$\rightarrow $HSV routines - I just use this example as it is easy to visualize - but in the real application the dimensionality would more like 70 input parameters ($m=70$), mapping to 20 output parameters ($n=20$) and possibly up to 50 coupled points defined ($p=50$).

So far I’ve tried:

- Using inverted Euclidean (or manhattan) norms found on the input
  side to inform weighted interpolations on the output.
- Euclidean norms building simultaneous equations (‘hyper-spheres'!) that are solved using [non-linear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares) ([trilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration) in higher dimensions and with over-fitting)
- Using [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) dimensionality reduction on m to ensure $m=n$

Each of these has had practical success of sorts (especially if the p-coupled pairs are consistent within their spaces, and the more the better).

But there are always examples where the solution falls apart: eg. with $m=n=2$ and $p=4$ and the coupled vectors:

$$[0,0]_{\mathbf{i}_1} \longleftrightarrow[-10,10]_{\mathbf{o}_1}$$$$
[100,0]_{\mathbf{i}_2} \longleftrightarrow [10,-10]_{\mathbf{o}_2}$$$$
[0,100]_{\mathbf{i}_3} \longleftrightarrow [-10,140]_{\mathbf{o}_3}$$$$
[100,100]_{\mathbf{i}_4} \longleftrightarrow [110,110]_{\mathbf{o}_4}$$

<sup><sup>(Note this is *not* an RGB>HSV example)</sup></sup>

With least squares the solution (the black dot on the right-hand plot) to the input point: $[10,5]$ should be closer to the pre-defined point 'o1':

[image]

(Note how close the input (black point on the left) is to 'i1')

My ad-hoc patches simply lead me to chase my tail - so...

### My questions:

While I’m aware that the nature of interpolation excludes precision, I ask:

1. *What approach would be the closest I can get to a solution that generalizes for all dimensions, and inputs ?* (within *and* outside the convex hulls defined in the $p$ coupled points)
2. Is there some other function of the input point with respect to the points pre-defined in the input space that I can glean information that would allow a more direct solution?
3. Is a direct and analytical approach even possible, or will I have to rely on measures of success via machine learning methods?

Comment: As far as I know, color spaces are no vector spaces.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich. Keep in mind the colour spaces are just an *example* application. As for the tag I'm not 100% sure exactly what a vector-space is myself, but after reading the tag description I figured that people interested in them may have an interest in this question (?). I am keen to remove bad tags though, especially if there is a better tag to put in it's place - I'm open to suggestions !  :)

Comment: Have you looked at multidimensional scaling (MDS)?

Comment: @user217281728, No - but I'm reading about it at wikipedia right now - it does however mention PCA as 'Principal Coordinates Analysis' [sic] as a technique involved (unless there is a Principal *Coordinate* Analysis?) ... Thanks for the comment though, the rest looks potentially relevant :)

Comment: Using the least squares approach, it fails as I am using the *absolute* measurements from the input space in the output context. Without knowing the answer I'm looking for (chasing my tail) I cant formulate a new set of *relative* distances in the output space (unless I use a bodge like 'average inter-point distance). So the MDS  dissimilarity matrix might be able to help me here?

Comment: for general non-linear function fitting $f : [0;1]^n \to [0;1]^m$  from $P$ pairs $(x_i,f(x_i))$ I'd say that there are numerous methods, all related, all converging to the function when  $\max ||x_i - x_j|| \to 0$ :
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm which is the simplest,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation and its generalizations, 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network ...

Comment: @user1952009, I've just read up on K-Nearest_Neighbours (regression) on wikipedia. Aside from using RMSE, this is what I was describing in my first bullet point of attempts... The issue was that if I made my pairs equivalent, then I would only mirror my input point back in the output in rare cases (when I was on a pre-defined point or when I was equidistant from all the points I was evaluating/interpolating over). I'll try to plot the differences in results over a grid of inputs...

Comment: @user1952009, Read up on KDS, in a similar way to MDS >> it's interesting, and can be applied in the described context, but I'm not sure how it actually helps give an answer?  Not discounting it, just saying I cant see it myself (yet)  :)

Comment: @Lamar Latrell : so you didn't understand kernel density estimation well, it interpolates from the neighbors by giving more confidence to the nearest. try with $K(x-x_i) = e^{-||x-x_i||^2}$. and nested kernel density estimation leads to neural networks : the most general framework for non-linear function approximation

Comment: @user1952009, I considered neural networks as my next step, but I thought a more direct and analytical approach might be lurking. It's helpful for you to point out that the $P$ pairs can be thought of as (or simply *are*) a functional relationship of input and output to $f$. I see the convergence also; perhaps my (k-NN) test cases are just too coarse in resolution to really worry about. I'd love an analytical solution if possible! Will try some NN's though, certainly worth a look in to :)

Comment: @Lamar Latrell :  you can interpolate the K-nearest neighbors values as you wish, for example by weighting in function of the distance (the kernel density estimation becoming the limit of KNN when $K \to \infty$) or by passing a polynomial trough the K points. there are so many methods, those are just some "general ideas" from which you create you own algorithm (using cross-validation to validate the best model) $\implies$ that's a [machine learning problem](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133776/kernel-density-estimation-vs-machine-learning-for-forecasting-in-large-samples).

Comment: @Lamar Latrell : kernel density estimation is what you are searching for. and if you don't like the obtained results, modify the kernel $K$ (which define a distance on the input space) and add the gradient of the function so your $P$ example points become $(x_i,f(x_i),\nabla f(x_i))$ from which you can estimate $f(x)$ more precisely at local extremas

Comment: I haven't had much statistical education compared to other areas (which aren't that great themselves) so there's a bit to digest here!  Reading, reading, thinking, thinking... Thanks in the meantime :)

Comment: Interesting section under 'interpolation' here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, no one else answers the bounty (?) I'll go with my own lead:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_network